# Why is the peak-to-peak separation of cyclic voltammetry is 57 mV?

Tags: electrochemistry, cyclic-voltammetry

I'm studying CV, and I wonder if I can calculate the peak-to-peak separation of CV for a reversible redox system.

I found that the separation is 57 mV on my textbook, and my teacher taught me that is can be calculated theoretically using Nernst equation,
but I think it is more complicated.

Is it easy enough (for sophomore) to calculate the value?
And if it is, I want to know the way.

(Sorry for my poor English)

Comment: The 57 mv is empirical and not related to the similar value from the Nernst equation.  It arises from the numerical solution of the equations in the oxidation/reduction cycle. See Nicholson & Shain Anal. Chem. v36, p 706 1964 for the  details of the calculation: not an easy read. In introduction is given by Mabbot J. Chem. Educ. v60, p697  1983 and Benschoten et al. ibid. v60 ,p772, 1983

Answer (score 1):

The derivation of equation for cyclic voltammetry requires a lot of advanced calculus and differential equations based on the Fick's law of diffusion. This is not to discourage you but to show that the teacher is oversimplifying it. The derivation are provided in Allan J. Bard's Electroanalytical Chemistry. Why are they teaching cyclic voltammetry in sophomore classes?

Comment: Actually I'm not a student at a usual university, so I'm not a sophomore, but in an equivalent grade.
I've heard about the Fick's law of diffusion but I don't know the detail, so I want to study more and more, and to understand the derivation.
Anyway, thank you for answering!

Comment: Good to know but Bard's book should be consulted. You will find the details there.